Generar pdf con JsPDF
soy nuevo en esto de generar PDF usando la libreria jsPDF, Tengo un problemita que quizás yo lo estoy haciendo, e introducido este código:



    
    
    
    GENERADOR DE PDF    


    Crear Pdf
    
    Generar mi PDF
<script type="text/javascript">

    function genPDF(){
        var doc=new jsPDF();
        doc.text(20,20,'Este es un texto en un PDF');
        doc.save('midocument.pdf');
    }
</script>

Resulta que al dar click en el enlace no me abre en otra pestaña, sino que automaticamente se abre una ventana para elegir donde guardar mi pdf...yo quisiera que se abra en una pestaña sin necesidad de tener que guardarlo.. ojala me deje entender

A ver si me dejo entender, yo no quiero guardar el documento, quiero previsualizarlo antes de guardar para ver si todo esta correcto..este codigo solo es una maqueta para todo lo que voy a hacer adelante pero yo no queiro guardar quiero previsualizar porque si veo un error en el pdf lo pueda corregir en el formulario que luego hare. Parece que el save me obliga a guardar... pero hay otro codigo que solo me haga previsualizarlo sin guardarlo?

En lugar de la llamada a:
doc.save('midocument.pdf');

Este código debiera hacer el trabajo:
window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), '_blank');

Otra alternativa es:
doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');


pero en que parte del codigo se pondría eso, como te vuelvo a decir soy nuevo

En lugar del doc.save().

pero eso crea una pestaña en blanco pero no el pdf

¿Ambas crean una pestaña en blanco siempre? ¿En qué navegadores y sistemas operativos has probado?
